# Get images from Highcharts PHP Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, highcharts

Good day, folks.

I am making something like CRM in Laravel, where users can see graphs and other cool stuff by Highcharts (based on their statistics). I also want to send them statistics each month in PDF (on email).

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy is great at making PDF.

However, then comes the problem: I want to include images from Highcharts to these PDF's. But Highcharts is a JS library. And it really provides function for exporting images from graphs.

So really the question is: 'How can I (inside Laravel/PHP) get images, which are created by JS?'

Maybe I must run also JS server like Node.js (I don't know, haven't experience with it) and somehow get images from it?

Comment: The highcharts allows you to return SVG by [chart.getSVG()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.getSVG) so only what you need is convert SVG to image or place it in your PDF.

Comment: Thanks, I 've solved the issue - I use same blade templates, which are used to show Highcharts to users, to create nice JSON for charts options. Then I start phantomjs server in PHP exec() like `phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -infile options_visitors.json -outfile visitors.jpg -scale 2.5 -width 2000 -constr Chart`. So I dynamically get pictures and on the next step they are also dynamically hooked by PDF creator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to save your images generated by Highcharts with the export module (http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview).

Once the image is saved in the server, then you can access them using PHP.

I hope it helps you!

Comment: I though about this. However, this is not good solution, cause 1) I need to export them, but when? 2) I need to keep them on the server. Moreover, I've already stated than I can export images in my question....

Comment: I think that may be the link I need
http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-articles/news/56-improved-image-export-with-phantomjs

Comment: Ok, I got your point now. I didn't know about that PhantomJS, it looks quite useful, please share it with us if you solve your problem using it.